# Started POST "/signup" for ::1 at ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserController Did you mean? UsersController):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, forms, post

I am not able to signup my user that is getting error while running post method for /signup route.

Please help !!!

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get    'signup'  => 'users#signup'
```

This is users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def signup
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        log_in(user)
        redirect_to(root_path)
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render('new')
    end
end

end





ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserController
Did you mean?  UsersController):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following line in your `routes.rb` from

```
post   'signup'  => 'user#create'
```

to

```
post   'signup'  => 'users#create'
```

because your controller is named `UsersController` (note the plural).